# Pipe to Soil Potential Measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, voltage-measurement

[image]

I want to measure pipe to soil potential using a microcontroller. Generally, the potential difference between pipe to soil is negative. I found this circuit online.

1. Is this circuit correct for measuring PSP (Pipe to Soil Potential)?
2. How could I measure the PSP by using ADC? Please suggest some article.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate your circuit? What is expected negative voltage range on your IN signal?

Comment: the voltage range is between -1 to -3 voltage

Comment: Please add that into your question by clicking edit. What you have above is a slight variant of a summing amplifier with a buffered reference. Depending on your ADC input range, you may want some gain but nothing critical unless you need very high resolution, at which point the reference calibration will be the more important factor. Again, please simulate it.